# How to order by an average rating

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am trying to order my products by the average of the ratings given in reviews of the product.

here are my tables:
**Product** : id, productname, price, approved
**reviews**: id, review, rating, product_id_fk

How would I change this to return on the highest average rating to the lowest?

```
$products = Product::where('approved', '=', 1)->orderBy('productname');
return view('pages.search')->with('products', $products)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new table called product_review_ratings containing

```
product_id
avg_rating
```

Create a scheduled command that loops through all products and sum avrage rating. Save to product_review_ratings table.

In the ProductReviewRating Model add a relationship to Product

```
class ProductReviewRating extends Model
{
    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }
}
```

Now you can sort by rating.`

```
$collection = ProductReviewRating::orderBy('avg_rating', 'desc')->get();
```

And in view

```
@foreach ($collection as $rating)

    {$rating->product->name} - {$rating->avg_rating} <br>

@endforeach
```

Example of scheduled command (assuming that you have reviews relation in product model)

```
foreach (Product::all() as $product) {

    ProductReviewRating::updateOrCreate(['product_id' => $product->id],[
        'product_id' => $product->id, 
        'avg_rating' => $product->reviews->pluck('rating')->avg()
    ]);

}
```

Comment: Any idea on what the 'schedule command' that would loop through would be?

Comment: @detinu20 do you know how to make a command? Solution coming up!

Comment: Where should i place the scheduled command in the model or in a controller? apologises my php laravel knowledge is sparse

Answer (score 0):

The easy way (no scheduled command needed) is to compute the avg() over the reviews and join the result with products:

```
$products = DB::table('reviews')
            ->join('products', 'reviews.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->select(DB::raw('avg(rating) as average, products.*'))
            ->groupBy('product_id')
            ->orderBy('average', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

make this a method in your products model, or better yet, products Repository.

Comment: Where is the ratings being averaged there?

Comment: Upps! My mistake. It is avg (rating) instead of avg(*). Answer edited.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'products.products.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select avg(ratings) as average, products.* from `reviews` inner join `products` on `reviews`.`product_id` = `reviews`.`id` group by `product_id` order by `average` desc)  - is an error i get on that code. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answers is quite outdated now.
There is a [builtin](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#other-aggregate-functions) `withAvg` eloquent function that can do the required job.

> These methods will place a `{relation}_{function}_{column}` attribute on your resulting models

So to get the average of the ratings from reviews table:

```php
Product::where('approved', '=', 1)->withAvg('reviews', 'rating')->orderBy('reviews_avg_rating');
```

Now you can use the product rating as easy as : `$product->reviews_avg_rating`
The resulted sql will be using subquery to get it on every product:

```sql
select `products`.*, (select avg(`reviews`.`rating`) from `reviews` where `products`.`id` = `reviews`.`product_id`) as `reviews_avg_rating` from `products`
```